# Question about the Poisson distribution

Tags: probability

I will first present the question at hand and then describe how I solved it.  Apparently my solution is incorrect and I cannot figure out why, so I was wondering if anyone here might have some insight.  (It is possible that it is correct, but someone told me it is wrong.)

> Suppose $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are independent with common distribution $\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$.  For $\nu\ge1$, consider the partial sums $S_\nu = X_1 + \cdots + X_\nu$.  Given any two non-negative integers $m\le n$, evaluate ${\bf P}\{S_m=j\mid S_n=k\}$ where $0\le j\le k$.

[(original screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Ypf.jpg)

So here is how I solved this.  I first noted that, by the stability of the Poisson distribution, $S_v \sim \text{Poisson}(v\lambda)$.  Then, I apply Bayes' rule to find that

\begin{align*}
P(S_m = j \mid S_n = k) &= P(S_n = k \mid S_m = j)\cdot \frac{P(S_m = j)}{P(S_n = k)}\\
&= P(S_{n-m} = k-j)\cdot \frac{P(S_m = j)}{P(S_n = k)}\\
&= \dfrac{((n-m)\lambda)^{(k-j)} e^{-(n-m)\lambda}}{(k-j)!} \cdot \dfrac{(\lambda m)^j e^{-\lambda m}/j!}{(\lambda n)^k e^{-\lambda n}/k!}\\
&= ((n-m)\lambda)^{(k-j)}  \cdot \dfrac{(\lambda m)^j}{(\lambda n)^k }\binom{k}{j}\\
&= \boxed{(n-m)^{(k-j)}  \cdot \dfrac{m^j}{n^k }\binom{k}{j}}
\end{align*}

However, apparently this solution is incorrect.  Can anyone provide any insight into where I went wrong?

Comment: which is the right answer?

Comment: I don’t know.  Someone told me that my answer was incorrect... it’s possible they were wrong though.  Personally I can’t figure out why this reasoning would be wrong.

Comment: I don't find any mistake in your computation. So at least, you and I have the same answer. :D

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe it is correct then...

Comment: It is correct, note that the final form can be rewritten as: $(1 - \frac{m}{n})^{k-j} (\frac{m}{n})^j {k \choose j}$, which means that $S_m | \{S_n = k\}$ is distributed as Binomial $\mathcal B(k,\frac{m}{n})$ random variable.